# Convertir códigos a caractéres especiales

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

¿Cómo puedo transformar con Javascript este tipo de palabras?

> Lu00f3gica, Anu00e1lisis.

Son palabras que contienen caractéres especiales como tildes, pero al salir de la `db` aparecen así, las correctas serías

> Lógica, Análisis

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con Javascript?

Ya tengo `charset` en `utf-8` y la db está en latin1_swedish_ci
Estoy usando PHP y mySQL

Comment: Con que lenguaje estas extrayendo los datos de la base de datos?

Comment: Con php y base de datos mySQL

Comment: Prueba con esto
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Donde con es tu conexion.

Comment: Antes o después? edito: antes no tendría caso jaja, ya lo intenté pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código PHP que genera o lee esos datos? En teoría PHP los debería decodificar correctamente, lo mismo que javascript si los recibe. En algún lado estás haciendo algo mal y sin código no podemos decirte dónde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer son **unicode** y no se te muestran las tildes porque les hace falta el `\` ejemplo:

```
L\u00f3gica, An\u00e1lisis.
```

Para reemplezar en el js esos caracteres se me ocurre algo como:

```js
let palabra = "An\u00e1lisis";

const unicodeReplace = (str) => {
  
  let unicodes = unicodeList();
  unicodes.map((unicode) => {
    
    let Re = new RegExp(unicode.unicode, "g"); //expresión regular para
                                               // para obtener todos los 
    str = str.replace(Re, unicode.utf8);       // unicode y reemplazarlos
    
  });
  
  return str;
}

const unicodeList = () => {
   //Aquí colocas todos los unicode que necesites
   let unicodes = [{unicode: "\u00f3", utf8: "ó"},{unicode: "\u00e1", utf8: "á"}];
  return unicodes;
}

alert(unicodeReplace(palabra))
```

Tambien te serviria sin el `\` pero debes de declararlo asi en la lista de **unicodeList**, ejemplo:

```
const unicodeList = () => {
   //Aquí colocas todos los unicode que necesites
   let unicodes = [{unicode: "u00f3", utf8: "ó"},{unicode: "u00e1", utf8: "á"}];
  return unicodes;
}
```

Comment: Esta función sólo modifica el primer unicode que encuentra, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que modifique varios unicodes existentes en una cadena?

Comment: Me imagino que hay muchas formas de hacerlo pero se me ocurre que conviertas la palabra en un array con el .split() y vayas pasando cada letra a la funcioncon un loop como un for

Comment: Encontré la forma ya la añadí a tu respuesta